# how to get view for any screen outside application?

Tags: android

I can not get view using `getWindow` inside service.

I used this view for any screen outside application.

```
View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
```

How can I capture screenshot inside service?

or how can I get view for any screen outside application?

Comment: please read these: [page1](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [page2](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) [page3](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Punch Line : You are very bad in asking questions.

But I will try to answers the questions that I understood.

**How do I take Screenshots?**

```
private void getScreenshot() {

try {

    String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + /*NAME*/ + ".jpg";

    View view = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    File imageFile = new File(imagePath);

    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
    int quality = 100;
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();

} catch (Throwable e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Do what you want to do with the screenshot now.

Also I did not understand what you wanted to to ask with,

`View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();`

You can clarify that further if you want.